# Implement the printTriangle method so that it prints an upside down triangle based on the parameter str

Tags: java

I am taking a computer science class at my high school we have recently learned about for loops and I think I somewhat understand but, for some reason I cant figure out why my code won't print out like this

Hello

Hell

Hel

He

H

public class TriangleTwo {

```
public void printTriangle( String word ) {
    // Going to need a loop with some prints or printlns. 

 for (int s = word.length() - 1; s >= 0; s--) { 

       System.out.println( word.substring(s, s + 1) ); 
  } 
  System.out.println(  );   

 }
}
```

y
d
w
o
H

e
l
t
t
i
L
_
n
e
k
c
i
h
C

^^I keep getting this back instead^^ can anyone guide me on how my code can print

Howdy

Howd

How

Ho

H

Thank You so much!

Comment: Have another look at your parameters to `substring`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is ok - but your substring is just grabbing 1 letter at a time.
Change the first s in Substring to a 0 (the start of the word)
So

```
    for (int s = word.length() - 1; s >= 0; s--) { 
        System.out.println( word.substring(0, s + 1) ); 
    }
```